# Blocking a website using GPO or Firewall in windows server 2012

Tags: group-policy, organizational-unit

Using windows server 2012, How to block any specific website on all browser using group policy?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here only prevent a user from accessing the website using the DNS name, **they don't stop them from accessing it via IP address**. Users are often more crafty than you think.

If you're going to assume the website has a fixed IP address (which isn't true for a lot of sites using geolocated web hosts and content distribution networks), the better option is simply to add an outbound block rule in Windows firewall for the IP addresses in question. This blocks a user using either the name or IP.

You can easily use Group Policy to deploy rules to Windows Firewall on all of your client systems.

Comment: Multiple websites are often hosted behind a single IP. Thus blocking the IP will block everything hosted at that location.

Comment: At the same time, you may also have multiple IPs for the same website, depending on which loadbalancer or endpoint they are accessing (if any). Blocking an IP also doesn't protect against future IP changes, so it might be feasible to design a script to poll the domain name for the latest IP address every so often.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will find here is that Group Policy Objects will work on Internet Explorer but not other browsers such as Firefox and Chrome.

You probably could push out a Firewall Policy but the best bet is it use DNS to block the site.  I've done it before and it works great.

**Use DNS to Block a Website**

This is assuming you are running a domain, which I would guess you are because of mention to group policy. Also the client machines will be using your domain DNS servers.

1. Open the DNS from MMC or log into Domain Controller and open DNS
2. Right Click Forward Lookup Zones -- New Zone
3. Primary Zone
4. To all DNS servers running on domain controllers in this domain (or forest if you have a forest)
5. Zone name will be the DNS name of the site, example: facebook.com (note there is no www)
6. Do not allow Dynamic Updates

**Add Records to the new Zone**

1. You will see the new zone under Forward Lookup Zones
2. Right Click the zone -- New Host (A or AAAA)
3. Leave Name Field Blank
4. IP Address - 127.0.0.1 (will redirect back to themselves)
5. Add Host
6. Repeat steps 2 - 5 for subdomains, add www or apps in the Name Field

**Adding a Blocked Message**

If your keen you could build a local webserver and create a custom block message using HTML, then instead of using 127.0.0.1 in the IP Address, put the IP address of the web server.  They will try to go to facebook.com but get displayed your block message.  I used to have a photo of Chuck Norris giving a thumbs up as part of my blocked message.  Got a few strange phone calls...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hosts file to block out certain websites. Create a group policy to update C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Then follow the guide [here](https://superuser.com/a/673950/167485)